# Can CVS checkout accepts pattern for module names?

Tags: cvs

I have a CVS repository with more than 1000 modules. The modules are named in a pattern based on project type.

For example:

- ROOT/repository/module_T1_projectA
- ROOT/repository/module_T1_projectB
- ....
- ROOT/repository/module_T2_projectA
- ROOT/repository/module_T2_projectA
- ....

Similare to the structure mentioned above, there are more number of modules. I want to know if I can use a single command to checkout all modules that matches a pattern. I am expecting a command something like the below

```
cvs checkout module_T1*
```

currently I have to checkout all these folders one by one like

```
cvs checkout module_T1_projectA
cvs checkout module_T1_projectB
....
cvs checkout module_T1_projectXX
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I suspect that the answer is No, given that wildcards are interpreted by the shell and not passed to application.